# how to add vertical divider between two columns that contains multiple bootstrap rows?

Tags: css, react-bootstrap

I am creating a form where users can pull up some transactions details. User should need to enter either (store,reg,tran) details or invoice number. I have added these in the form and i want a vertical divider between these input sections. Ideally, that will show a or sections in between them.

I have tried multiple suggestions from the internet and but nothing seems to work for me. I have multiple rows in the first column and only one row in the second column. I have tried https://codepen.io/lyndenoliver/pen/WpYPBp?editors=1100 this example but this puts the divider after the first item in each row within the first column

```
<div>
 <div className="container-fluid">
     <div className="row">
         <form className="col s12" id="storeReportForm" onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
             <div className="row">
                 <div className="col s12 m6">
                     <div className="row">
                         <h6 className="col s12 m2 required-field" >Store</h6>
                         <div className="input-field col s12 m3">
                             <input id="store" type="number" className={`validate ${selected.store}`} maxLength="4"
                                 value = {this.state.store}
                                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                                 onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
                             <label htmlFor="store">Store</label>
                         </div>
                         <h6 className="col s12 m2 offset-m1" >Terminal</h6>
                         <div className="input-field col s12 m3">
                             <input id="terminal" type="number" className="validate" maxLength="4" 
                                 value = {this.state.terminal}
                                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                                 onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
                             <label htmlFor="terminal">Term</label>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div className="row">
                     <h6 className="col s12 m2" >Account</h6>
                     <div className="input-field col s12 m3">
                         <input id="account" type="number" className="validate" maxLength="4" 
                             value={this.state.account}
                             onChange={this.handleChange}
                             onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
                         <label htmlFor="account">Last 4</label>
                     </div>
                     <h6 className="col s12 m2 offset-m1" >Amount</h6>
                     <div className="input-field col s12 m3">
                         <input id="amount" type="text" 
                             className = {this.state.amountSelected === 'true' ? 'valid' : ''}
                             value = {this.state.amount}
                             onChange={this.handleDecimalChange}
                             onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
                         <label htmlFor="amount">Amount</label>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 </div>

//need a vertical line here with text or like in the codepen example 
                 <div className="col s11 m5">
                         <h6 className="col s12 m2 required-field" >Invoice</h6>
                         <div className="input-field col s12 m3">
                             <input id="invoice" type="number" className={`validate ${selected.invoice}`} maxLength="4"
                                 value = {this.state.invoice}
                                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                                 onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
                             <label htmlFor="invoice">Invoice</label>
                         </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Need a vertical separator that indicates the user can give any one of the inputs

Answer (score 0):

after struggling for a while this is how i added the divider

```
<div className="col" style={{marginLeft:'10px',marginRight:'10px'}}>
                                    <div className="row vertical-line"></div>
                                    <div className="row" style={{paddingTop:'90px'}}> OR </div>
                                    <div className="row vertical-line"></div>
                                </div>
div.vertical-line{
  width: 1px; /* Line width */
  border-right: 1px solid #26a69a;
  height: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```